# Find enclosing characters in grep

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I want to find all instances of `?[A-Za-z0-9]?` -- any and all text which is surrounded by two question marks and highlight the question marks themselves instead of the text inside.

Find:

```
?North America?
```

Don't find

```
Is anyone there?
```

Comment: Note that `[A-Za-z0-9]*` does not match `North America` since the latter contains a space.. Did you mean `.*` or just `[ A-Za-z0-9]*` (note the space in the beginning of the brackets) ? Also, we must assume that the text surrounded by the question marks is limited to a single line, or else it could also match `Is anyone there?` (if the previous line contained a question mark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through grep,

```
grep -Po '\?.*?\?' file
```

OR

```
grep -oE '\?[^?]*\?' file
```

To highlight only the question marks.

```
grep -P '\?(?=[^?]*\?)|(?<=\?)[^?]*\K\?' file
```

Example:

```
$ cat fi
foo ?North America?
Is anyone there?
$ grep -P '\?(?=[^?]*\?)|(?<=\?)[^?]*\K\?' fi
foo **?**North America**?**
```

`**?**` means highlighted `?` marks.

Use the below Perl command to replace surrounded `?` marks with single quotes.

```
perl -i -pe "s/\?(?=[^?]*\?)|(?<=\?)[^?]*\K\?/'/g" file
```

Comment: Unfortunately that highlights all question marks in the text. Perhaps there's not a way of expressing what I need using grep? This is a csv file if that helps understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: the above command works for me. Why you want to highlight `?` marks?

Comment: I'm not using the command line, I'm using the grep search in TextWrangler. I want to highlight ? marks since there was an encoding error when exporting a huge database to csv and it has made it so everything which used to be surrounded with single quotes is now surrounded by question marks. Do I need the -P in TextWrangler? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I don't know about `TextWrangler` . But yep, you must need to add `-P` (perl-regex) parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65595/discussion-between-benjaminjb-and-avinash-raj).

Comment: Nothing, I was waiting to give you a bounty and only just remembered. Thanks for your help over chat and patience.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 'foo?C?bar' | grep -Eo '\?[A-Za-z0-9]\?' | grep --color=auto '\?'
```

Output with highlighted `?`:

```
?C?
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to hightlight words between question marks:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Term::ANSIColor;

my $bold=color("bold blue");
my $normal=color("reset");
my $str='?North America?
Hi ?aa ? aaa
Hello?
kkk?asad0098? a ?
';
$str =~ s/(\?[A-Za-z0-9]*\?)/$bold$1$normal/g;
print $str;
```

Output:

[image]